# LWJGL Not installing correctly

Tags: java, eclipse, lwjgl

So I've been trying to set up LWJGL for the past 2 and a half hours or so looking at every tutorial. I believe I'm doing some incorrect because none of them work. You see, I put down a basic function such as `Display.create();` and for some reason "Display" is not importing. The only suggestions Eclipse gives me is "Create a constructor, class, etc" for "Display". While browsing the web I discovered that it should be imported like `import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;` however it's not suggesting any imports related to that. Neither is `DisplayMode`, that just comes up with a java.awt import.

So, some help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you include the various jars in the Java Build Path ?
Go to your project configuration, try a setting like this :

[image]

Comment: Yes, I've put in lwjgl.jar and lwjgl_util.jar into there correctly. I've also set up my natives and Javadoc.